# Java - Splitting with both words and symbols

Tags: java, regex, split

I have a string like `String str = "void Write(int *p,int a)"` I want to get function name "str" and parameters names "*p" , "a". However, I will not know how many parameters there are.

I have written `"int\\s+|void\\s+|string\\s+|float\\s+|double\\s+|char\\s+\\(,\\)"` for regex.

Part 1 = `Write(`   Part 2 = `*p,`  Part 3 = `a)`

The last part of regex `\\(,\\)` was for removing semicolon and brackets. But it failed as you see. Do I have to use a second split or is there another way ?

Comment: That doesn't look like task for regex but C/C++ parser.

Comment: I'm trying to find and count functions of a C code using Java

Comment: Using Java is not the problem, using regex is.

Comment: So you're saying that I can't do it using only one split ?

Comment: Maybe it is possible, but it would be extremely harder to handle all valid cases which parser handles. For instance method declaration in C can be done using many lines, but it looks like your regex solution handles only one line. Regex doesn't know what was in previous and what is in next line. I am not expert on writing parser/compiler but I would probably avoid using regex here (unless you have extremely well defined data which you want to handle and handling it doesn't require recursion).

Comment: Ok. Let's say we know that it will be in the same line. How can we remove both int,void,... and brackets ?

Comment: regex is short for regular expression, or a syntax for expressing rules around a _regular language_ (as defined in CS theory / etc). Languages (fancy way to say anything written) that are not a _regular language_ (oversimplified: a finite and deterministic writing)  can therefor not be expressed in plain regex (and needs extension modifiers for doing being expressed). This is why you'd have better luck with a parser/interpreter that can read these things symbol by symbol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be a two step process

Step 1: Extract functional name and all arguments

Step 2: Extract each argument name from the list of all arguments

Step 1:

Lets apply this regex `^\S+\s+([^(]+)\(([^)]+)*` to this string `void Write(int *p,int a, int b, str *v)` this test string

```
^         # start of string
\S+       # one or more occurence of any non space charactcers
          # matches `void`
\s+       # one or more occurence of a space character
          # matches the space after `void`
([^(]+)   # all characters until opening parenthesis
          # matches `Write` and capture it
\(        # literally matches opening parenthesis
([^)]+)   # matches all characters till closing parenthesis is encountered
          # matches arguments signature i.e. `int *p,int a, int b, str *v`
*         # matches zero or more occurrence of last capturing group
          # last capturing group is string between the parenthesis
          # so this star handle the corner case when the argument list is empty
```

More details: https://regex101.com/r/0m1vs9/2

Step 2

Now to the argument list (`int *p,int a, int b, str *v`) apply this regex `\s*\S+\s+([^,]+),?` with global modifier

This patterns matches text between commas so lets explain the patterns assuming the same

```
\s*      # matches zero or more occurrences of a space character
         # this will match any spaces after comma e.g. `int b,<space> str`
\S+      # one or more occurrence of non space character
         # matches argument type, i.e. `int`
\s+      # one or more occurrence of space characters
         # matches the space between argument name and type, e.g. `int<space>b`
([^,]+)  # capture all characters till comma
         # this matches the actual argument name
         # and also matches any spaces after it
,?       # zero or one occurrence of a comma
         # this ensures that the argument name is immediately followed by a comma
         # this also handles the case for the last argument which doesn't have any comma after it
```

More details: https://regex101.com/r/9ju60l/1

Hope that helps